# AngularJs $watch throws Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive that looks like this:

```
app.directive('superDir', function ()
{
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('elements', function (value, old)
        {
            element.replaceWith(scope.elements.join(""))
        },true);
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
});
```

however then the `elements` array is modified and the `$watch` is triggered I receive an exception :

```
Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
```

the html looks like this :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <super-dir></super-dir>
</div>
```

Can you tell me why it's not possible to replace a `super-dir` tag?

Thanks

Comment: Try `angular.element(element[0]).replaceWith(...)` instead of `element.replaceWith(...)`. But I think you should look into a directive template.

Comment: replaceWith accepts html wrapped with quotes. you are passing scope itself.

Comment: I'm passing `scope.elements.join("")`, and it's a string containing html since every element in scope.elements is an element itself

Comment: please show scope.elements object.

Comment: here it is :
`['<div style='background-color: #ff0000; display: inline-block;'>APPENDED</div>
',
'<div style='background-color: #ff0000; display: inline-block;'>APPENDED</div>']`

Answer (score 6):

*I know this is a bit late, but I was busy with the same problem for a day now, and I investigated the issue.*

I assume, that what you want to achieve is a **dynamic loading and switching of a template at runtime**.

The reason you get the error in the `replaceWith()` call lies in the internal use of the `.find()` method and in principle you (*just like me*) are doing *it* **wrong**, with wrong meaning, not the *Angular way*.

**You are trying to replace the element, that defines the directive. You can imagine the element *BEING* the directive (*if you put water into a teapot...*).**

This can be done at the link function, but after the directive is set up and a part of the DOM, you would kind of remove the directive itself from the DOM by replacing it, which does not play well with how Angular's selectors work.

So what you can do instead, and what I am doing now is... just replace its contents!

```
var renderTemplate = function (scope, element, template) {
    var loader = Pages.getTemplate(template, false);
    var promise = loader
        .success(function(html) {
            var rendered = $compile(html)(scope);
            element.empty();
            element.append(rendered);
        });
};
```

So your directive either has a wrapping element you replace it with in the standard template, or you do not replace the element it all. Either way, replace the **content** of your directive and not the directive itself and it should work correctly!

*Become like the water, my friend.*

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue and can confirm this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to console.log your element inside the watcher? or maybe

```
if(typeof element != 'undefined' && element != null) { ..... }
```